# How quickly can one compare exp(m/n) to a given rational?

Tags: computational-complexity, exponential-function, floating-point

For positive integers $\hspace{.06 in}m_{\hspace{.02 in}0}\hspace{.02 in},n_0\hspace{.02 in},m_1,n_1\:$, $\;$ how difficult is it to decide whether $$\exp\left(\hspace{-0.03 in}\frac{m_{\hspace{.02 in}0}}{n_0}\hspace{-0.04 in}\right)-\frac{m_1}{n_1}$$
is positive or negative? $\;$ In particular, can that be decided in [polynomial time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_%28complexity%29)?

(A consequence of the [Lindemann-Weierstrass Theorem](http://planetmath.org/lindemannweierstrasstheorem) is that the above expression won't be zero.)

If it could be done efficiently, then that would give a way around the

[table-maker's dilemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#The_table-maker.27s_dilemma) for the exponential and natural log functions.

Comment: Since the rationals are dense, I would guess arbitrarily difficult.

Comment: I would guess it's about finding a sequence converging quickly towards $e^{\frac{m_0}{n_0}}$ while having a good error bound. A suggestion would be to use the power series definition on $e^{-\left|\frac{m_0}{n_0}\right|}$, since it's an alternating series, and thus the next term is a working error bound. This is doable in polynomial time to any given accuracy.

Comment: It seems related to the result and discussion of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.5429.pdf).